# Declare a .d.ts file of a JS dependency that exports a function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using a dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-class) in my typescript project. This dependency doesn't have a @types definition, so, until now I've working with a custom .d.ts file with `declare module 'is-class';` to make the import work. However, I want to add types to this dependency.

is-class basically exports a single function that receives 1 parameter and returns boolean. I've been trying to add this to my .d.ts file but everything that I've tried so far throws one error or another, my best guess so far is:

```
declare module 'is-class' {
    function isClass(a: any): boolean;
    export = isClass;
}
```

In my ts code:

```
import * as isClass from 'is-class';
// ...
const foo = isClass(bar);
```

This throws the message: `This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.` but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just encountered a similar issue.

First I updated tsconfig.json to include a couple new options:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    }
}
```

(This isn't the whole config file. I just excluded options that previously were already present.)

I changed the import line to something like this:

```
import isClass from 'is-class';
```

And the declaration file looks basically like you described:

```
declare module 'is-class' {
    function isClass(a: any): boolean;
    export = isClass;
}
```